# Use PowerShell to find each user on a computer and drop a shortcut in their startup

Tags: powershell, shortcuts

I have a great PowerShell script that will put a shortcut in the all user’s startup folder. The problem is that I have some computers that have users already that need the same shortcut but won’t get it because their profile is already created on that computer. So, what I need is a way to find each user on the computer and then drop the shortcut into their startup folder.

If I were using VBA it would be something like "do until" or "for each user", how do you loop like that through PowerShell?

Oh, here is the PowerShell to place the shortcut in the all user folder:

```
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$objShortCut = $objShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" + "\HipChat.lnk")
$objShortCut.TargetPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\HipChat4\HipChat.exe"
$objShortCut.Save()
```

Comment: FTR, here's [how to loop in PowerShell](http://www.winserverhelp.com/2010/04/powershell-tutorial-loops-for-foreach-while-do-while-do-until/). I found this by searching "PowerShell for each".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem is that...users...need the same shortcut but won’t get it because their profile is already created on that computer.*

**That's not correct.** Items created in the `All Users` locations (Startup, Desktop, etc.) affect all accounts on the computer, both future and existing.

If you're creating an item in the All Users Startup folder and existing users cannot see it, make sure the new item's permissions are set correctly. One simple way to do this is to edit the Advanced Security Settings for the folder *containing* the new item (e.g. the Startup folder) and choose **Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permission from this object**:

[image]

There shouldn't be any unusual permission that require preservation in a folder like this one, making this a quick way to ensure all items, including your newly added one, have the proper permissions.